# Holes designed in water spigot?

Tags: plumbing, faucet, hose, spigot

https://youtu.be/mhYfr3y6Jkw

See the video above for what I'm referencing. I noticed water shooting out from my spigot today (never seen this happen before).

Upon closer inspection it looks like it actually has holes designed in it (so I have no clue why this hasn't happened before).

How can I prevent water from shooting out of those holes in the water spigot? The garden hose is fully tightened already.

Comment: that is a vacuum breaker ... if the tap is turned on, and the end of the hose is in a dirty puddle, and the water pressure in the city water supply drops, then the puddle water could be sucked into the water system ... the vacuum breaker allows air to be sucked in, instead of the contaminated puddle water

Comment: [Here you go.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQUXMZICq7o)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like there is something screwed onto the end of the spigot, probably a backflow preventer. Try to unscrew the wide ring that you are connecting the hose to. These wear out and/or get gummed up and stop working properly.

For reference. here is a photo of such a device I found on the internet:
[image]

Comment: The spring loaded flap seal failed.+1 Stay safe out there.